# Fixing the background's position with JS is choppy

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I fix position of div's background in JS to create a parallax effect (background-attachment works not so well for my goal). But sometimes it works so-so: background may change position not immediately.

An example is here: https://youtu.be/SshLhAfD3oY

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("e4AAAgCw3OA-960.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: var(--check);
}
```

JS:

```
function parallax() {
    document.body.style = `--check: ${window.pageYOffset}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    parallax();
});
```

Any ideas?

I tried using *window.scrollY* instead, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Javascript. I advise to use `background-attachment: fixed` in CSS.

Change your CSS like this:

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("e4AAAgCw3OA-960.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

---

This is an example of the parallax scrolling effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.fixed-bg {
  background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>In this example, we have created a fixed background image that will disappear slowly on scroll. Scroll the page to see the effect. <strong>Note:</strong> Try to remove the background-attachment property to really understand this example.</p>
 
<div class="fixed-bg"></div>

<div style="height:800px;background-color:yellow;">This div is only here to enable scrolling (height = 800 pixels).</div>

</body>
</html>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_background-attachment_fixed

Comment: As I said, background-attachment is buggy. For an example, this doesn't even work at Safari and background is shaking because of attachment at any browser on Android .

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed` is full supported in Safari 15.4 and Android browsers. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment#browser_compatibility)

Comment: maybe it is, but I tested and it didn't work
anyway on android browsers it has a bug: when you scrolldown a bit, the background for some reason become bigger and change its position